# How can I automatically generate a new input area when user started to enter text?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, web

I want to generate input dynamically. Searched almost all samples and they generate inputs with button clicks. It is ok but i need something different. When user started to type in input then i want to create second input and when user typed to second then create third input like this..

My problem is when user typed inputs then it creates many inputs (letter counts=inputs). I must solve this issue immediately . I tried to some tricks but they could not work . Thanks for helping . You can check it in Codepen .

```
  <div class="container1">
      <button class="add_form_field">
        Add New Field &nbsp;
        <span style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">+ </span>
      </button>
      <div class="divInput firstChild">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="mytext[]" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var max_fields = 10;
        var wrapper = $(".container1");
        var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".divInput");
        let xs = [];
        var x = 1;
        $(add_button).click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;

            $(wrapper).append(
              '<div class="divInput"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="delete"></a></div>'
            ); //add input box
          } else {
            alert("You Reached the limits");
          }
        });



        $(wrapper).on("keyup", "input", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          if ($(this).val() == "") {
            //when user cleaned input then delete it
            $(this).parent("div").remove();
            x--;
            return;
          } else if ($(this).val() != "") {
            //dont use click check if length>0 then use this trick to add new input
            $(add_button).trigger("click");
            return;
          }


          if (x == 0) {
            //if user tries to delete last input then create a new one
            console.log("xx", x);
            $(wrapper).append(
              '<div class="divInput"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="delete"></a></div>'
            ); //add input box
            x = 1;
            console.log("xx", x);
            return;
          }
        });
      });
```

https://codepen.io/otontas11/pen/BaogrZR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to store in the current id in the input, make an event when user types and check the input id and check if is already added, if not then you proceed.

You need to attach the event to the **body** since you are dynamically creating elements.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="generatedChild">
        <input type="text" childId="1" autocomplete="off" name="mytext[]"/>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    var max_fields = 10;
    var wrapper = $('#container');
    // attach the event to the Body, so all generated inputs will be listened by our event
    $('body').on('input','.generatedChild input' ,function(e){
        currentId = $(this).attr("childid");
        childId = parseInt(currentId) + 1;
        childOfThisInput = $(`input[childid=${childId}]`);

        // check if is already added or if exceeds the maximum fields number
        if(currentId > max_fields || childOfThisInput.length === 1) return;

        $div = $("<div>", {class: "generatedChild"});
        $input = $('<input>', {childid: childId, autocomplete:"off", name:"mytext[]", type: "text"});
        $div.append($input);
        wrapper.append($div);

    });
});
</script>
```

**Update:**
If you need to let the user delete some of the generated inputs you can try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var max_fields = 10;
    var wrapper = $('#container');
    var inputsLength = 1;
    // attach the event to the Body, so all generated inputs will be listened by our event
    $('body').on('keydown','.generatedChild input' ,function(e){
        currentId = $(this).attr("childid");
        childId = parseInt(currentId) + 1;
        childOfThisInput = $(`input[childid=${childId}]`);
        if($(this).val() === "" && e.key === 8 && inputsLength > 1 )
            return remove_input($(this));
        // check if is already added or if exceeds the maximum fields number
        if(inputsLength > max_fields || childOfThisInput.length === 1 || e.key === 8) return;
            add_input(childId);
    });
    function add_input(childId){
        $div = $("<div>", {class: "generatedChild"});
        $input = $('<input>', {childid: childId, autocomplete:"off", name:"mytext[]", type: "text"});
        $div.append($input);
        wrapper.append($div);
        ++inputsLength;
    }
    function remove_input(element){
        element.parent('.generatedChild').remove();
        // let's focus the last generated input, so user won't need focus the input again
        $('.generatedChild input:last').focus();
        --inputsLength;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes it worked . just a small mistake a have when a tried to delete input value i face with a problem  ```if ($(this).val() == "") {
          
            $(this).parent(".generatedChild").remove();
          }``` just one input should remain even if user wants to delete all inputs by one by

Comment: I see. I edited my answer and added some code to get you in the right way on deleting generated inputs

Comment: yes it works i just changed ```keydown to keyup``` nnd later it worked exactly. after doing some arrangements i started to use it . You saved my day nd maybe week :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is mostly *an* opinion, but IMO you shouldn't mix jQuery with react, they use fairly orthogonal ways to accomplish UI manipulation.

Here is a way I accomplished this design

```
const createInitialState = initialValues =>
  initialValues.map(value => ({ id: uuidv4(), value })); // id used internally

const createOnChangeValues = values => values.map(({ value }) => value);

const InputList = ({ defaultValues = [], onChange }) => {
  const renderRef = useRef(null);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [values, setValues] = useState(createInitialState(defaultValues));
  const [inputFocused, setInputFocused] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (renderRef.current) {
      onChange && onChange(createOnChangeValues(values));
    }
    renderRef.current = true;
  }, [onChange, values]);

  const addValue = value => {
    if (value) {
      setValues(values => [...values, { id: uuidv4(), value }]);
      setInputValue("");
    }
  };

  const updateValue = index => e => {
    const updateValue = e.target.value;
    if (updateValue) {
      setValues(values =>
        values.map(({ id, value }, i) => ({
          id,
          value: index === i ? updateValue : value
        }))
      );
    } else {
      setValues(values => values.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!inputFocused && inputValue) {
      addValue(inputValue);
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [inputFocused, inputValue]);

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addValue(inputValue);
  };

  const resetHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInputValue("");
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form id="inputForm" onReset={resetHandler} onSubmit={submitHandler} />

      {values.map(({ id, value }, i) => (
        <div key={id}>
          <input value={value} onChange={updateValue(i)} />
        </div>
      ))}

      <div>
        <input
          form="inputForm"
          ref={inputRef}
          type="text"
          value={inputValue}
          onFocus={() => setInputFocused(true)}
          onBlur={() => setInputFocused(false)}
          onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>

      {inputValue && (
        <div>
          <input />
        </div>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

The gist is you have *some* array of inputs currently being used, and you always render an extra blank input. As soon as user starts filling the new blank input it becomes part of the array of inputs upon losing focus. If any input becomes blank it is removed from the array. Much of the logic is to manage the swap from the new/empty input to one in the array and keep focus.

Usage

```
<InputList defaultValues={[... input values from state]} onChange={... values from inputs in array} />
```

[image: Edit InputList]

Comment: this is exactly what i need but problem is it is written in react js:) and thank you so much for answering :)

Comment: @Oktaytontaş Is that an issue? You tagged the question with the `reactjs` tag.

Comment: yes because reactjs developers are amazing developers generally and ı thought they can help. and your answer is so professionel and it will be hard a bit understand it for me